# how to redirect rewritten query-string URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am using following rules

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [NC,L]
```

To rewrite following URL

```
mynews/category.php?cat=News
mynews/category.php?cat=News&subcat=9
```

to

```
mynews/News/ 
mynews/News/9
```

It is being rewritten only. But how to redirect automatically these querystring URL to rewritten URL ?

I have used following rules as suggested in answer, but doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /category\.php\?cat=([^&]+)&subcat=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /category\.php\?cat=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /%1/? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a few rules to do external redirects. These redirect rules will need to be placed before the rewrite rules that you already have. So they'll look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /category\.php\?cat=([^&]+)&subcat=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /category\.php\?cat=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /%1/? [L,R]
```

These will see requests that are `/category?cat=<something>` and externally redirect the browser to the nicer looking URLs. The reason we need to match against `%{THE_REQUEST}` is so that we make sure there's no chance the rewrite rules that you already have interfere with the redirect rules because the rewrite engine will loop through the rules.